# Code to check whether site has been listed on search engines and directories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, seo, bing, yelp, yellow-pages

I am currently developing an application in Rails, which requires to check whether a website has been listed in Google, Bing, Yahoo, Yelp and Yellow Pages. From my research the best is to check site: domain.com on Google and Bing and look for results and check in Yahoo directory for the domain.

Is there any other way to do it? I mean some code snippet to check on domain's home page or using their API or something like that. Also how to check on Yelp and Yellow pages.

Answer (score 1):

You can use mechanize and write web-style drivers
Google: do a search on your domain with this on the search term

```
site:checkmeout360.com
https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3A<SITE_NAME>.com
```

Try to see how yelp, yahoo, bing and yellow pages do indexing.  Then you can use mechanize to automate the searching process for you, you can use mechanize to do the search like above with google, then write asserts (check if stuff you are looking for is on the search result)

Comment: Thanks.I already know about getting results google and bing.Thanks for the mechanize idea.I was not able to find whether site is listed in yahoo.Any help help there would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Search engines don't appreciate automated queries that are sent their way.

Here is what [Google has to say about it](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=66357):

> Google's [Terms of Service](http://accounts.google.com/TOS) do not allow the sending of automated queries of any sort to our system without express permission in advance from Google. Sending automated queries consumes resources and includes using any software (such as WebPosition Gold) to send automated queries to Google to determine how a website or webpage ranks in Google search results for various queries. In addition to rank checking, other types of automated access to Google without permission are also a violation of our [Webmaster Guidelines](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=35769) and Terms of Service.